# Example with MIPS, Pipelining and Branch Delay Slot

Tags: assembly, mips, pipeline, risc

I am preparing for a test and have such example. Following code:

```
1: SLL $1, $1, 2
2: LW $2, 1000($1)
3: BEQL $2, $0, END
4: ADDI $3, $2, 1
5: MULT $3, $2
6: MFLO $4
END:
7: J QUIT
...
QUIT:
100: NOP
```

is executed on RISC processor (with quasi MIPS instruction set) with

- **five-stage pipeline**
- **no** bypassing
- **no** dynamic scheduling
- **Branch Delay Slot**
- Additionally we know, that **branch won't be taken**

My task is to understand how the Branch Delay Slot works in this situation and build the correct Pipeline Diagram.

I have an official solution and it gives the following diagram with no explanation:

```
1: SLL $1, $1, 2         IDEMW  
2: LW $2, 1000($1)        I---DEMW  
3: BEQL $2, $0, END           I---DEMW  
4: ADDI $3, $2, 1                 IDx
5: MULT $3, $2                       IDEMW
6: MFLO $4                            I---DEMW
```

As far as I understand, ADDI is executed in Branch Delay Slot and is stopped
after processor understands, that branch is not taken, what leads us to wrong result. My Questions here are

- Am i right?
- When yes, why is ADDI executed in Branch Delay Slot and not Jump?

Comment: If branch is **not** taken then why would `ADDI` be stopped? In fact, why would it be ever stopped? Instructions in the delay slot get fully executed, no matter if branch is taken or not.

Comment: AFAIK the typical 5 stage MIPS pipeline splits register access in two phases, so `D` phase of a dependent instruction can happen in the same clock as `W` of its dependency, even without explicit forwarding.

Comment: 2Jester Well, in our conventions (maybe not so real) in case of Branch Likely instruction, like here, instruction in BDS is stopped by wrong prediction. The question is why ADDI and not J.

Comment: @EOF It's not exactly MIPS. Here we have only IF, DE, EX, ME and WB phases for all instructions. And the diagram is an official solution, so i consider it's right.

Comment: Looks like some advanced MIPS IV feature ( http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/mips-iv.pdf ) - indeed, `ADDI` is thrown out (page 45). What do you mean *"why ADDI but not jump"*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CPU keeps reading instructions sequentially, i.e. during execution (was already fetched, decoded and the remaining phases are now being processed, I don't know your exact phases, so this is just general description) of `beql` it will get the other part of pipe free to fetch next instruction, but the branch was not finished yet, so the `PC` is still pointing to the next instruction after branch -> that's the "branch delay slot".

On classic MIPS this next instruction is fetched, decoded, and executed, and meanwhile the branch may or may not modify the PC to the branch target, so the branch-delay slot instruction will get executed every time. The next instruction after it gets executed only when branching didn't happen, i.e. the `PC` continues after the "branch delay slot" position sequentially. In case the branch did modify the `PC`, the fetch+decode will take notice and decode the next instruction from new destination, so on classic MIPS the branch delay slot is only 1 instruction "big" (I have no idea if more complex MIPS CPUs can have more stages and more delay slots available, technically with 5 stage pipeline even 5 instructions delayed sounds HW possible, but it would be probably very difficult to use practically and sounds like it would create more problems than help).

The `BEQL` is more complex instruction, killing the delay slot instruction halfway into execution if the branching condition fails.

See http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/mips-iv.pdf page 45 for detailed description of `BEQL`.

So that "NullifyCurrentInstruction()" is probably that "x" in the diagram. Remaining things in diagram, I'm just guessing as I didn't study your 5 stage details, but second `LW` after fetching and decoding(?) finds out it depends on `$1`, so it waits in depend-stage for previous instruction `W` phase. Etc...The `ADDI` doesn't depend on anything, so it is executed almost parallel to `BEQL`, and gets killed toward the end.

But I don't understand why there's no "I" phase every time the "I" stage gets freed, looks like the "I" waits for something and in the end you have like at most 2 instructions going on at the same time.

Anyway, this is quite undecipherable without studying the technical details of the CPU used in your question, and I don't want to study it, I'm not even sure what kind of CPU you have, and where to get it's technical documentation.

---

edit: I will try to extract relevant part of pdf also here, to make this answer not "just link", but copying pdf may be tricky...

`BEQL` instruction docs of MIPS IV CPU:

> Description:
>   if (`rs` = `rt`) then branch_likely
>   An 18-bit signed offset (the 16-bit offset field shifted left 2 bits) is added to the address of the instruction following the branch (not the branch itself), in the branch delay slot, to form a PC-relative effective target address.
>   If the contents of GPR `rs` and GPR `rt` are equal, branch to the target address after the instruction in the delay slot is executed. If the branch is not taken, the instruction in the delay slot is not executed.
>
> Operation:
>   I:
>     tgt_offset ← sign_extend(offset || 0<sup>2</sup>)
>     condition ← (GPR[rs] = GPR[rt])
>   I+1:
>   if condition then
>     PC ← PC + tgt_offset
>   else
>     NullifyCurrentInstruction()
>   endif

Comment: Ah, didn't know about the "likely" family.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it explains everything for a real MIPS processor. But the problem is that assembly we use in this course is something similar to MIPS, but not it exactly. And our BEQL executes the first instruction of branch target in delay slot - here this should be J QUIT.

Comment: @J.Doe ah... that doesn't make much sense from HW design point of view (I mean, it would be next to impossible to create such CPU while maintaining the multi-stage pipeline advantage, decoding instruction from target address would force the performance to go near the levels of classic single-instruction processing), but if your CPU is designed like that, then who am I to object... But the correct answer is using `ADDI` as branch delay slot instruction. So something is wrong. Ask lector, what is correct?